# how to use same script on all locations i need?

Tags: jquery, location, toggle

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.panel
{
height:20px;
display:none;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
    $(".panel").toggle();
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<TABLE border="1">
<TR>
 <TD>to see whats hidden under here press to image</TD>
 <TD>IMG SRC=".jpg" WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" BORDER="0" ALT=""</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<div class="panel"><p>Haa haa, nothin</p></div>

<TABLE border="1">
<TR>
 <TD>wanna see what under here?</TD>
 <TD>IMG SRC=".jpg" WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" BORDER="0" ALT=""</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<div class="panel"><p>treasure from bottom of ocean</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Porblem is, when i press first or second image i see the first thing thats hidden and second thing thats hidden. I want to make so that when i press first image i see only what hidden under there and i can toggle it, not just show and never hide again.

Comment: `$(".panel")` means "everything that has `panel` in its CSS classes. You need to narrow it down to pick the specific panel you're interested in, hence the `closest('table').next(".panel")` from sje397.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('table').next(".panel").toggle();
  });
});
```